# "Hobby time" is it meaningful phrase?

Tags: sentence-construction, phrases

For one of my FB post I titled "Became a hobby time Android app developer" Here, I got a doubt, is "hobby time" correct phrase?

Comment: Probably you mean "part-time" Android app developer.

Comment: Yes.I do also want to make the sentence to mean the activity is interesting that's why I used Hobby time instead of part-time. because part-time means the activity not necessarily to be interesting. Thank you for your comment.

Comment: @Robusto: to my mind, part-time relates to work, not to a leisure activity. https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/part-time

Comment: Perhaps you are looking for the word *amateur*.

Comment: @BillyKerr: perhaps you should read the answers before commenting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This [NGram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=hobby%20time&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Chobby%20time%3B%2Cc0) shows that the phrase **hobby time** is not common, but it is used, for example

> plan to set aside a portion of the hobby time you already spend for maintaining your new site. [The weblog handbook](https://books.google.co.id/books?id=BAY4DgAAQBAJ&pg=PT28&dq=%22hobby%20time%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjjlKqK7PTYAhUkT48KHfwDDOE4HhDoAQgmMAA#v=onepage&q=%22hobby%20time%22&f=false)

In your proposed sentence, **hobby time Android app developer** is a compound noun... and quite a long one at that. I have looked through the examples that NGram provides, and cannot find any instance of a compound noun using hobby time.

Maybe that's because there is a better way of expressing the same idea, using the word **[amateur](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/amateur)**, for example

> Become an amateur Android app developer.

This [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=hobby%20time%2C%20amateur&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Chobby%20time%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Camateur%3B%2Cc0) shows how much more frequently **amateur** is used rather than **hobby time.

Your proposed sentence is perfectly grammatical, but there are certainly better ways of expressing the same idea.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. I am happy about the experience with the ELL.  I rarely used amateur word in my conversation or in my writing. thanks for reminding me to use it. in this title, What I really tried to say is an interesting activity that could be done in their leisure time. So I am unsure about replacing hobby-time with amateur, which actually means beginner/learner.thanks for mentioning that my title is not grammatically wrong. otherwise I would have been in guess. If by any chance of leaving a reply to my comment, I request your feedback on my English.

Comment: If you follow the link to the definition of amateur in my answer, you will see that amateur does not  mean beginner/learner. it actually means **taking part in an activity for pleasure, not as a job**. I think that it is ideal for an interesting leisure time activity.